# how to use datatable in ng bootstrap modal in angular

Tags: angular, datatable

How can I draw data table in ng bootstrap modal in angular. I Used bootstrap and angular-data tables module. I want to draw data table in bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 0):

simply add datatable code in body part of modal

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>table code here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to use ng modal like this <ng-template #content let-modal> <div class="modal-header"> <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Profile update</h4> <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button> </div> <div class="modal-body"> </div> <div class="modal-footer"> </div> </ng-template>

Comment: Then put your table inside <div class="modal-body"> </div>.

Comment: @kamlesh did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same issue where the dtElement is undefined because ng-template is not in the DOM at the time the DatatableDirective is trying to bind